# How to insert or update a column using SQL based on sorted number of items for each item group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables 'Product' and 'product_Desc'

```
+-----------+-------------+
| ProductID | ProductName |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 | A           |
|         2 | B           |
+-----------+-------------+
    


      +----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| Id | ProductID | ProductDec  | SortOrder |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 | Aero-pink   |           |
|  2 |         1 | Aero-white  |           |
|  3 |         1 | Aero-green  |           |
|  4 |         1 | Aero-Orange |           |
|  5 |         2 | Baloon-1    |           |
|  6 |         2 | Baloon-2    |           |
|  7 |         2 | Baloon-3    |           |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

Now, what is the Sql code that can update 'sortOrder' column sequentially for each group of ProductID as shown below:

```
    +----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
    | Id | ProductID | ProductDec  | SortOrder |
    +----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
    |  1 |         1 | Aero-pink   |         1 |
    |  2 |         1 | Aero-white  |         2 |
    |  3 |         1 | Aero-green  |         3 |
    |  4 |         1 | Aero-Orange |         4 |
    |  5 |         2 | Baloon-1    |         1 |
    |  6 |         2 | Baloon-2    |         2 |
    |  7 |         2 | Baloon-3    |         3 |
    +----+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

Please note that these are sample tables, actual tables have thousands of records.
Would appreciate your help on this. Thank you

Comment: Your source and target tables look identical to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes the top one i.e 'Product' is master/Parent table and below to that 'Product_description' is child table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte
as
(
select SortOrder, row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by Id) as newPerProductOrder 
from product_Desc
)
update cte
set SortOrder = newPerProductOrder
where (SortOrder <> newPerProductOrder or SortOrder is null)
```